# Объект Slider в WPF и его элемент управления Thumb?

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с элементами wpf , и у меня возник вопрос по компоненту slider - на msdn написано, что

> Представляет элемент управления, позволяющий пользователю сделать выбор из диапазона значений, передвигая элемент управления Thumb вдоль Track.

- но экземпляр slider не предоставляет доступа к своему элементу управления Thumb. Если создавать экземпляр Thumb - вручную, то можно ли его как то "связать" с уже существующим slider?

Comment: Сделать то что хотите?

Comment: Получить доступ к Thumb текущего slider , но не знаю как это сделать

Comment: @BadCats что в итоге сделать хотите? Зачем вам доступ к Thumb?

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, но я что буду пересказывать суть всего проекта или получу ответ на чисто технический вопрос?
Доступ к Thumb нужен для того, что бы в зависимости от того где этот
Thumb  находится на slider -записывать определенные значения в массив

Comment: @BadCats, у слайдера есть свойство Value посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо , посмотрю

Comment: Ваш вопрос похож на проблему [XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy) поэтому и были заданы уточняющие вопросы о том, что вы _на самом деле_ хотите сделать.

Comment: И после вашего комментария, согласен с @Gardes - свойство `Value` как раз то, что вы искали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thumb содержится в шаблоне элемента Slider, это вовсе не означает, что нужно получать доступ к нему, чтобы узнать где он находится. Для этой цели Slider предоставляет свойство `Value`.